# How to view the properties of a service template reference?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

We are using an ARM json template which has this:

```
"outputs": {
        "gatewayurl": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/uat1api'), '2018-01-01', 'Full').properties.gatewayUrl]"
        }
```

What exactly is `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/uat1api` ?
How can I go into `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/uat1api` and view the `properties`?

I can see that the value ends up being https://uat1api.azure-api.net/, but I'd like to go in and see where that value is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.ApiManagement/service` is the **resource type** while `uat1api` is **the name of the resource** (in your case, in API Management Service).

Properties are specific to each resource type and defined in a `template reference` (link below for API Management Service).

Another great resource is the `Azure resource explorer`. Not all properties are documented in template reference while the resource explorer seems to provide a more accurate visibility on properties available on each resources.

[Microsoft.ApiManagement service template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service)

[Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com)